# ASP.NET Core on Linux Web Space

Tags: asp.net, linux

With the help of a Udemy course I am learning ASP.NET Core MVC. The course is this one:

https://www.udemy.com/course/aspnet-core-mvc-configuracion-e-implementacion-net-6/

I haven't finished it yet, but I already have a question: Is it possible to host the application on a Linux based webspace, where .NET Core is not installed and to make it worse, I don't have root permission to install it? On this webspace I can host Wordpress, Joomla, HTML+CSS etc. Is it possible to publish the ASP.NET Core MVC application in such a way, that everything that is needed is included?

Thanks in advance for your help.

René

Answer (score 0):

You can run .NET without having the .NET runtime installed on a machine by publishing it as a "self contained" application:

`dotnet publish -r linux-x64 --self-contained true`

Whether your hosting provider will then allow you to execute that particular application though would probably need testing.

For more information on self-contained publishing, you can find the docs here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#publish-self-contained

Comment: Even with a web app (in this case ASP.NET Core MVC)?

Comment: For any sort of .NET application, yes.

Comment: Thank you. I tested this right away on my main hoster, which is Debian based and does not support .NET. Unfortunately I couldn't even run a "Hello world!" even though I created and published the mini-app as you describe and also Microsoft. Is it known that there are hosters that prevent running such applications?

Comment: You may need some extra libs, such as libssl, depending on what dotnet packages you're using. I'm not sure of any way to automatically add them to your deployable, unfortunately. Here's a link describing some of the Linux package dependencies; https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/main/Documentation/self-contained-linux-apps.md